# Remove row in datagrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

In ASP/VB.net

In my DATAGRID i'd like to remove a row in Grid_ItemDataBound

I have already try 
[How to remove row from datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814819/how-to-remove-row-from-datagrid)
 But is not really that i need

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataGrid.ItemCommand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemcommand.aspx)

Sample code:

```
  void ItemsGrid_Command(Object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
  {

     switch(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).CommandName)
     {

        case "Delete":
           DeleteItem(e);
           break;

        // Add other cases here, if there are multiple ButtonColumns in 
        // the DataGrid control.

        default:
           // Do nothing.
           break;

     }

  }

  void DeleteItem(DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
  {

     // e.Item is the table row where the command is raised. For bound
     // columns, the value is stored in the Text property of a TableCell.
     TableCell itemCell = e.Item.Cells[2];
     string item = itemCell.Text;

     // Remove the selected item from the data source.         
     CartView.RowFilter = "Item='" + item + "'";
     if (CartView.Count > 0) 
     {     
        CartView.Delete(0);
     }
     CartView.RowFilter = "";

     // Rebind the data source to refresh the DataGrid control.
     BindGrid();

  }
```

Comment: I not have taht : The ItemCommand event is raised when any button is clicked in the DataGrid control. This event is commonly used to handle buttons controls with a custom CommandName value, such as Add, in the DataGrid control.

Answer (score 0):

If DataGrid is bounded to a source, ie datatable remove the datarow from the source (datatable) and then rebind the grid to the datasource.

```
...
    dtable.rows(i).Delete
    myDataGrid.DataSource = dtable
    myDataGrid.DataBind
...
```